# How to show list of countries which something more than EDITED

Tags: r, shiny

EDITED
I would like to ask you how to do that simple thigs.
I want to make Shiny Web application that get from interface ammount of something (`inputId=num`), and show the table with countries that 
`data$both>num`
I made some code, but it doesnt work.

```
    library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(


  sliderInput(inputId = 'num',label = 'Countries that...',min = '1',max =189',value = '20',step = '1')
  tableOutput(outputId = 'liczba')

)
    server <- function(input, output) {


  output$liczba <- renderTable({
    data[data$both>input$num,]
  })
}
  shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Why you are voting like that and dont left any comment?  Thats not serious . Clown fiesta

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? What works and where does it fail?

Comment: I want to make on web shiny application table that  get through interface minimal ammount of something(In my case - Average daily intake in grams of alcohol)  and make table in interface with countries that fulfill it. I dont know how to apply it on server.r.     data$country is a list of countries, data$male is a ammount of daily intake in grams

Comment: By the way I've edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution based on your code. There are several small errors in your implementation. Please take a look [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) for a set of very good examples.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data <- data.frame(
  country = c("Germany", "Netherlands", "Canada"),
  male = c(15, 30, 45)
)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    sliderInput(
      inputId = 'num',
      label = 'Countries that...',
      min = 1,
      max = 189,
      value = 20,
      step = 1
    )
  ),

  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("liczba")
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$liczba <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    result <- subset(
      data,
      data$male > input$num
    )
    result
  }))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```